# jQuery looping through an array (products/dates) and calculating price off consecutive counts

Tags: jquery, arrays

Trying to work out the logic on something and was looking for any sort of pointers.

I have a list of 6+ days. I already have a counter on each of these div's that counts how many consecutive days it is. The reason is because if you book an product for 01/30/17, 01/31/17, and 02/01/17 you get a discount based on the consecutive number of days in a row. The chain starts over if there's a break in the days, as you can see below when it starts over at `consec="1"` again. The discount only looks back 4 days and calculates what price each product should be at.

For example:

- Standard Price: 50
- 2 Consecutive Days Price: 45
- 3 Consecutive Days Price: 40
- 4 Consecutive Days Price 35

Let's say a user books one of the product for consec day 1, three for day 2, two for day 3, five for day 4, and two for day 5.

Day 1: They would get the 1 product at a regular price. **Total: 50**

Day 2: They would get 1 product at a "2 Consecutive Days" discounted price, and 2 products at the regular price since it's now a part of a previous chain. **Total 145**

Day 3: They would be getting 1 product at a "3 Consecutive Days" discounted price (from day 1 and day 2), and 1 product at a "2 Consecutive Days" discounted price and none at the regular price since there's none that weren't part of a chain. **Total 85**

Day 4: They would be getting 1 product at now a "4 Consecutive Days" discounted price (since there was at least 1 for all 4 days), 1 product at a "3 Consecutive Days" discounted price (not 3 because day 3 went down by 1, and 1 is still at the 4 day price), and then 3 at the regular price because the day before it only has 2, both of which are already accounted for at larger discounts and because those 3 are brand new for that day, essentially. **Total 225**

Day 5: This day stops taking into account anything on Day 1, because the consecutive discount only goes back by 4 days straight. It has 2 products at the "4 Consecutive Days" price because there was at least 2 products going back 4 days straight. **Total 70**

So this is kind of confusing...

What I'm trying to do is whenever any qty on an input with a `data-product-id="1"` is modified, change the calculated price of every single row it might affect.

I've tried going through this each statement a few different ways, the first way I tried checking the `consecDayCount` and if it was 4 or greater do some logic, and if it was 3 do other logic, and if it was 2 do other logic. This ended up to be a nightmare and never functioned properly. Ran into problems if one of the days didn't have this product in it.

I'm thinking it'll need something to do with arrays or multidimensional arrays? Looping through them and somehow keeping track of how many are at each price, adding that price together to get each total price for the price input.

All I need is the price input populated with the correct total, I don't need to list each individual price anywhere.

Any suggestions on how best to loop this and calculate each of them would be great. Really want to understand the best possible method.

```js
$('.date-row').on('change keyup', '.qty', function() {
  var productId = $(this).data('product-id');
  var consecDayCount = $(this).closest('.date-row').data('consec');
  if (productId == 1) {
    var standardPrice = 50;
    var consPriceTwo = 45;
    var consPriceThree = 40;
    var consPriceFour = 35;
    $('.qty[data-product-id="1"]').each(function() {
                 // where I'm running into trouble
                 // insert some missing logic to calculate each Qty level
      //var standardQty = $(this).val(); // is this what you meant? (- not left by question asker)
      // Not really, the standardQty would be the only qty in only 
      // the case where none of the products will be given a 
      // consecutive day discount.
      // standardQty is the qty of products at the standard price, 
      // which must be calculated based off how many of the previous           
      // consecutive days products carry over, like in the example. (- response from question asker)
     
      var dateRow = $(this).closest('.date-row');
      var priceInput = dateRow.find('.price');

      var standardTotal = standardQty * standardPrice;
      var consPriceTwoTotal = consTwoQty * consPriceTwo;
      var consPriceThreeTotal = consThreeQty * consPriceThree;
      var consPriceFourTotal = consFourQty * consPriceFour;

      var newPrice = standardTotal + consPriceTwoTotal + consPriceThreeTotal + consPriceFourTotal;

    });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-row" date-consec="1">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="date-row" date-consec="2">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="date-row" date-consec="3">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="date-row" date-consec="4">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="date-row" date-consec="5">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="date-row" date-consec="6">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>

<div class="date-row" date-consec="1">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="date-row" date-consec="2">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="date-row" date-consec="3">
  <input name="qty" class="qty" type="number" data-product-id="1">
  <input name="price" class="price" type="text">
</div>
```

Note in the HTML that the bottom 3 divs have their consec date start over, because they're not on days connecting to the other days, let's say in this example that they're at the end of the month while the first set is at the beginning of the month. So their consecutive discounts would be starting over.

Comment: You are missing a closing `')` before `.each()`, so your code it won't run. Here `$('.qty[data-product-id="1"].each(function() {` more exactly, should be `$('.qty[data-product-id="1"]').each(function() {`

Comment: I made a snippet, fixed a selector but am missing `standardQty` - perhaps `var standardQty = $(this).val()`

Comment: @Ionut even `$('.qty[data-product-id="1"]')`

Comment: @lonut Ah yes, sorry trying to copy this all over to here I must've mistyped that.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, the logic I'm running into issues with is calculating all of those qty's. They should be being calculated off the other boxes in how many consecutive days they are.